# is there a way to allow make to parse variables properly with trailing spaces and comments?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

From the `make` documentation

> Since trailing space characters are not stripped from variable values,
>   just a space at the end of the line would have the same effect (but be
>   rather hard to read). If you put whitespace at the end of a variable
>   value, it is a good idea to put a comment like that at the end of the
>   line to make your intent clear. Conversely, if you do not want any
>   whitespace characters at the end of your variable value, you must
>   remember not to put a random comment on the end of the line after some
>   whitespace, such as this:
>
> ```
> dir := /foo/bar    # directory to put the frobs in\
> ```
>
> Here the value of the variable dir is ‘/foo/bar    ’ (with four
>   trailing spaces), which was probably not the intention. (Imagine
>   something like ‘$(dir)/file’ with this definition!)

Is there a way to allow make to parse `dir` properly so that it is just `/foo/bar`? Or has the entire `make` community just accepted that you are not allowed to have comments on the same line with spaces separating them?

seems kind of silly considering end-of-line comments are very useful

Comment: You can: 1) put your comment on the previous line, or 2) use `$(strip)` to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces (`$(strip $(dir))`). Note that, in many circumstances trailing spaces are not a problem.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet or you can 3) write `dir := /foo/bar#  directory to put... `

Comment: Also consider `mkdir horror\ \ \ ` works just fine...

Comment: @Vroomfondel You're right but it does not answers the OP's question: *have comments on the same line with spaces separating them*.